# How do I prevent OrbitControls from causing the camera to jump?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene with objects that users can move around using TransformControls. Unfortunately, when a user drags the TransformControls to the edge of the canvas, the OrbitControls cause the camera to jump from its current location.

I believe this is because the TransformControls prevent default mouse events from bubbling up, but when the mouse is dragged toward the edge of the screen the TransformControls stop handling the mouse movement first and then the OrbitControls start handling it. I can isolate the situation with the following code:

```
this.orbitControls = new OrbitControls(this, canvas);
this.lastCameraAngle = this.rotation.toVector3();
this.orbitControls.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (this.lastCameraAngle) {
    const angleDifference = this.rotation.toVector3().angleTo(this.lastCameraAngle);
    if (angleDifference > 1) {
      // Occurs when user drags TransformControls to edge of canvas
      console.log('Error occurred!'); 
    }
  }
  this.lastCameraAngle = this.rotation.toVector3();
});
```

The question is, how can I actually stop the problem? I would strongly prefer a solution that doesn't require editing ObjectControls.js or TransformControls.js

Comment: Are you opposed to disabling `OrbitControls` while performing transformations?

Comment: Not at all! But I have tried disabling them when transform controls get selected and re-enabling them on mouseup events and as soon as they are re-enabled and the cursor moves over the canvas the jump occurs.

Comment: My suggestion is to have the user manually place your app into a "transformation state." When placed in that state, it it disables `OrbitControls`, and will only accept transformation input. When the user is done transforming, they switch your app into a "navigation state" which will re-enable the `OrbitControls`. Anything else would require modifying `OrbitContros.js`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure the bug occurs often enough to make the user go through an extra step every time they make a transformation. I guess if that's what it comes down to I would rather modify the source file, it just makes it tricky when the three.js devs update the OrbitControls in the future.